# каким образом можно сформировать массив в post запросе из полей формы?

Tags: php, html, массивы, post, input

суть: в форме 5 строк(может быть и не 5), в каждой из них по 2 поля(назовем группой), каждая группа относится к определенной строке в бд(в бд имеет id и эти 2 поля). сами группы в html выводятся в цикле, каждой группе приписывается id(принадлежность к строкам в бд), при отправке формы я получаю все поля подряд, нужно понять либо как их группировать до отправки, либо максимально лакончиный способ работы с кучей данных

$a:

```
    Array ( 
[0] => Array ( 
[ID] => 1 
[forms_email] => 525, 123
[form_id] => 1 
[form_name] => form_comp 
[active] => N ) 
[1] => Array ( 
[ID] => 38 
[forms_email] => 532523 
[form_id] => 2 
[form_name] => TESTED 
[active] => N ) 
[2] => Array ( 
[ID] => 44 
[forms_email] => 
[form_id] => 6 
[form_name] => 5566 
[active] => N ) )
```

форма:

```
<?for($i=0;$i<count($a);$i++){?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?=$a[$i]["form_name"]?></td>
                    <td><input type="text" value="<?=$a[$i]["forms_email"]?>" name="field<?=$a[$i]['ID']?>">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="check<?=$a[$i]["ID"]?>"> Активен?</td>
                    <input type="hidden" name="id<?=$a[$i]["ID"]?>" value="id<?=$a[$i]["ID"]?>">
                </tr>
   <?}?>
```

что приходит в post:

```
[field1] => 525, 123
[check1] => on
[id1] => id1
[field38] => 532523
[check38] => on
[id38] => id38
[field44] => 
[id44] => id44
```

вопрос в том как лучше эти данные занести в таблицу в БД(учитывая что checkbox если не выбран не приходит). field и check - поля в таблице, id - для идентификации

Comment: Какой-то непонятный салат. Что конкретно не понятно? Предоставь код наглядно и что не получилось

Comment: Автор, ты где? Поговори со мной :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

спасибо за ответы, сделал сам следующим образом:

```
<?for($i=0;$i<count($a);$i++){?>
<tr>
<td><?=$a[$i]["form_name"]?></td>
<td><input type="text"value="<?=$a[$i]["forms_email"]?>" name="field<?=$a[$i]['ID']?>">
<input type="checkbox" <?if($a[$i]["active"]=="on")echo"checked"?> name="check<?=$a[$i]["ID"]?>"> Активен?</td>
<input type="hidden" name="<?=$i?>" value="<?=$a[$i]["ID"]?>">
</tr>
<?}?>
<input type="hidden" name="count" value="<?=count($a)?>">
```

в обработчике:

```
$update=$request->getPostList();
for($i=0;$i<$update["count"];$i++){
    namespaces\class\ListTable::update($update[$i], array(
        "forms_email" => $update["field".$update[$i]],
        "active" => $update["check".$update[$i]],
    ));
}
```

это bitrix. в кратце поясню что тут написано:

прилетает post, мы начинаем цикл от 0 до count(по этому же циклу формировались поля в html из базы, т.е. количество соответствует), в форме есть поля имена которых - итерации цикла(0,1,2,...), их значения - id полей в БД, 2 других поля названы `field<?=$a[$i]['ID']?>` , т.е. мы указываем конкретную строку в БД, так же с чеком. и пробежав по циклу мы обновим все поля всех строк в БД, задача решена

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

    $a = array(
        0 => array(
            'ID' => 1,
            'form_name' => 'form_comp',
            'forms_email' => '525, 123',
        ),
        1 => array(
            'ID' => 38,
            'form_name' => 'TESTED',
            'forms_email' => 532523,
        ),
        2 => array(
            'ID' => 44,
            'form_name' => 5566,
            'forms_email' => '525, 123',
        )
    );

    foreach($a as $i => $value) {
        $id = $a[$i]['ID'];
        $fn = $a[$i]['form_name'];
        $fe = $a[$i]['forms_email'];

        echo <<<HTML
        <tr>
            <td>$fn</td>
            <td>
                <input type='text' value='$fe' name='field=$id'>
                <input type='checkbox' name='check=$id'>Активен?
            </td>
            <input type='hidden' name='id=$id' value='id=$id'>
        </tr>
HTML;
    }

?>
```

[image: исходный код]

Comment: Насколько я понял, код выглядит как-то так

Comment: Я обычно использую id при группировке полей. Тогда можно получить данные из POST по ключу из бд.

Comment: @ilyaplot, Сейчас толком не пойму что хочет автор. При изменении input'а сохраняться что-то должно с галочкой или нужна кнопка на сохранение

Answer (score 0):

```
$a = isset($_POST['a'])?$_POST['a']:0;
$b = isset($_POST['b'])?$_POST['b']:0;
$c = isset($_POST['c'])?$_POST['c']:0;
$d = isset($_POST['d'])?$_POST['d']:0;
$e = isset($_POST['e'])?$_POST['e']:0;
$stmt = $db->prepare("insert into table (a,b,c,d,e) values (?,?,?,?,?)");
$stmt->bind_param("iiiii",$a,$b,$c,$d,$e);
```